# Getting the max value out of a tuple in a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary declared as following:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<long, long>, Tuple<double, long>> dict= new Dictionary<Tuple<long, long>, Tuple<double, long>>();
```

How do I get the max value of Item2 of all dictionary values?

Comment: Dictionary key is a tuple ?

Comment: What exactly you mean by *max value of Item2 of all dictionary values* ?

Comment: `Dictionary<Tuple<long, long>, Tuple<double, long>>` sounds like a maintenance nightmare, you should probably change it to something clearer.

Comment: Why is your key a tuple?  A good reason for it, or are you just trying to get a list of items?  If so use List<Tuple<double, long>> instead.  You can use Max in the answer below on any Enumerable collection.  If you want, post your code on Code Review and link to it here.  Might be a much nicer way of doing whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `Max` LINQ method like this:

```
long max = dict.Values.Max(x => x.Item2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Max method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx). Not entirely clear which one of these you're asking for:

```
var maxKey = dict.Max(x => x.Key.Item2);
var maxValue = dict.Max(x => x.Value.Item2);

var maxEither = Math.Max(dict.Max(x => x.Key.Item2), dict.Max(x => x.Value.Item2));
```